# How to judge whether selected date has exceeded the range in UIDatePicker?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, uidatepicker

Now I have set the minimumDate and maximumDate of UIDatePicker like this

```
_timePicker.minimumDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:60];
_timePicker.maximumDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:86400*10];
```

and I have added a target

```
[_timePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(labelContentDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

I want to show an alert when a user has selected date which is not in that range, but every time the labelContentDidChange is invoked, the date property has been changed automatically and I can't get what the user has selected before, for example, if I select time currently, the datePicker will scroll to time one minute later,**and the date I get in labelContentDidChange is already one minute later.**

Comment: Read documentation of minimumDate and maximumDate, why would you ever expect a control to send events of changed value when you directly specified such values to be invalid input ? It's not bad to leave a fail-safe validation, but to want such notifications is something I can't understand.

Comment: I want to show an alert when selected date exceeded the range I set, so I think I should know what user has selected,  maybe minimumDate should not be used in this situation, now I don’t set minimumDate and check date by myself, if it is not in the range then I set date manually and show an alert.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe compare date that user have picked to minimum and maximum dates?

// assume we have NSDate* pickedDate

```
NSDate *minimumDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:60];
NSDate *maximumDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:86400*10];

// if picked date is earlier than minimumDate, OR if it is later than maximumDate - show alert
if ([pickedDate compare:minimumDate] == NSOrderedAscending ||
    [pickedDate compare:maximumDate] == NSOrderedDescending) {
        // show your alert
    } else {
       // valid date was picked
    }
```

Though if you set these minimum and maximum as properties to your datePicker user would not be able to choose invalid dates, it would only makes sense for some other custom periods of times...